# How to do load test in global region using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

We would like to do load testing from multiple regions using Jmeter. Our application is deployed in AWS. Below are the options we have right now

1. Create micro instances in AWS in multiple regions and test from there
2. Create virtual machines from Google cloud engine (Free trail) and test from there

We heard first option is not a simulation of real situation Because requests from AWS to AWS would have dedicated line so there won't be any latency. Is that true ?

Or Should we go with second option ?

Or Any other option we have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either option should work out fine.  I believe what you are referring to is more along the lines of AWS Direct Connect.  If the site you are load testing against are accessible externally, it is a good chance you will get the same behavior from your micro instance.  You can always do a traceroute on the micro instances to see the network connectivity.  If you are unsure, you can spin one instance in AWS and one in Google and compare the network.

Additionally, you can use third party service like Blazemeter to perform load testing of your JMeter script.

Answer (score 0):

There is a service for exactly this, called Blazemeter: https://www.blazemeter.com/

jmeter tests running on the cloud from any region.